# Insert/update bulk data mysql php in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I wants to batch process insert/update operations on multiple tables. I have few tables for insert/update actions for each activity. Which sometimes cause load average high of DB server if multiple activities going on parallel.

So i am willing to batch process insert/update on these tables like

```
BEGIN
INSERT....
UPDATE...
...
END;
```

How to achive this in php/mysql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into mysql's [Load Data Infile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) syntax. It's MUCH quicker than SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it faster by grouping inserts:

```
Insert into table (col1, col2) values (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6);
```